# What is the best way to stream video via a website built with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, video, video-streaming

I am looking for everyone's opinion on what is the best way to stream video from a website built with ASP.NET.  Some notable items include:

- The ability to stream .avi, .mpg, and possibly .wmv files
- The ability for someone to upload a video directly to a shared server and have it stream without any additional work needed (no compression needed, etc.)

I thought that Silverlight might be a good way to go, but I would greatly appreciate everyone else's opinions (please include pros/cons if you can).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some obvious options come to my mind:

- Flash - it's a popular industry-wide standard, but isn't native to Microsoft's .NET Framework.
- Silverlight - implementation and consumption of it favors .NET developers, but, while it's slowly picking up steam, it's not a widely-accepted standard yet and is greatly overshadowed by Flash's seniority and popularity.

EDIT:
Being the .NET developer that I am, I'd go with Silverlight in a heartbeat.

Comment: Flash has been out longer but Silverlight's adoption rate is picking up speed very quickly, that said I think they are both great products...

Answer (score 0):

I would use the asp:mediaplayer, which is in fact Silverlight.